# Why am I getting wrong result Math.Cos?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, math

Why when I tried to take a cos of 90 degrees I get some weird value other than zero? `Math.Cos(90 * Math.PI / 180)`

**PS: I'm aware that Math.Cos function take radians instead of an angle.**

Comment: and what is this "weird value" you're seeing?

Comment: What is "some weird value"? Can you provide what you DO get vs what you are expecting?

Comment: 6.1230317691118863E-17 @StealthRabbi | Theo

Comment: That's very *close* to zero.

Comment: `6.1230317691118863E-17` is `6.12 * 10^-17` so actually `0.0000000000000000612` (I may be off by one 0) which is pretty much `0`. The reason it's not exactly `0` is the representation of floating point values. It's a kind of rounding issue.

Comment: It may be a difference of running in Debug vs Release mode, as, I believe, Debug gives you higher floating point precision.

Comment: The value seems to be close  to `0.000000000000000061230317691118863`, which is 'near zero'.

Comment: Thank you all :), I was being tricked by Scientific-notation.

Comment: That is also an issue with Radians..... since 90 * math.pi/180 doesn't ever return pi/2 since math.pi is already truncated.....